# Configure custom key mapping for plugin actions

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, comments, plugin-nerdcommenter

I am using https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/ plugin to comment the code. It's working fine, but I would like to do a modification.

Currently these are the default mappings:

- `<leader>cc` comments the line
- `<leader>ci` inverts the comment
- `<leader>cu` undo last comment/uncomment action

I am looking to map `<leader>cc` to the action of invert comment i.e. `<leader>ci`. It's not a nerdcommenter question, but a question of vim mappings itself, hence asking here.

I tried

```
nnoremap <leader>cc <leader>ci
```

and also

```
nmap <leader>cc <leader>ci
```

But there doesn't seems to be any effect of these mapping. On pressing `<leader>cc`, I am seeing original action of it not the one I am trying to define.

**EDIT**:
FYI, answer to this question https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/763/8092 doesn't help either. i.e. to define custom mappings in `.vim/after/plugin/somefile.vim`

Comment: Does it work to put this in your `.vim/after/plugin/somefile.vim`: `call s:CreateMaps('nx', 'Invert',     'Invert', 'cc')`

Comment: It __is__ a nerdcommenter question, since the answer can be found in the manual: `nmap <Leader>cc <Plug>NERDCommenterInvert`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Thanks That works. But this is a generic issue i.e. "how to map/override a shortcut of a plugin with something else/user defined". Hence posted here.

Comment: No, it's a plugin-specific question. Remove any reference to NERDCommenter and rework the title to make it a generic question.

Comment: `nmap <leader>cc <leader>ci` works here when I source my vimrc file manually (but not when vim opens). What I suspect is that your mapping gets overridden by the plugin.

Comment: You can use `verbose nmap <leader>cc` to see where the mapping was defined.

Answer (score 1):

Like many other plug-ins, NERDCommenter creates internal mappings using the `<plug>` virtual key as a prefix, that you can use to map your own key-bindings to.

See [`:help NERDCommenterMappings`](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter/blob/c62e618a1ab5a50a4028e3296500ba29d9b033d8/doc/NERD_commenter.txt#L872):

> To change a mapping just map another key combo to the internal `<plug>` mapping.
>
> For example, to remap the `NERDCommenterComment` mapping to `,omg` you would put
>   this line in your vimrc:
>
> ```
> map ,omg NERDCommenterComment
> ```
>
> This will *stop the corresponding default mappings from being created*.
>
> See the *help for the mapping in question* to see which `<plug>` mapping to
>   map to.

So:

- You can find which `<plug>` mapping to use by looking it up at the help for the original mapping.
- NERDCommenter will not add its default mapping if it finds another mapping pointing to the `<plug>` mapping already, so you can use that to prevent it from creating its own mappings (such as `<leader>cc`), potentially overwriting yours.

Note that these mappings need to be recursive, since the `<plug>` ones are mappings themselves.

In your case, I believe this is what you want:

```
nmap <leader>cc <plug>NERDCommenterInvert 
xmap <leader>cc <plug>NERDCommenterInvert
```

This mapping is relevant in Normal and Visual modes, therefore remapping it with `nmap` and `xmap` here.

Note also that since you're using a default mapping of NERDCommenter, you'll need to remap *that* `<plug>` mapping to some other key, in order to prevent NERDCommenter from overwriting your mapping. For example, to use `<leader>ci` for the Comment mapping (effectively swapping the two keys):

```
nmap <leader>ci <plug>NERDCommenterComment
xmap <leader>ci <plug>NERDCommenterComment
```

But note that you don't need to use `<leader>ci` here, you can use *any* other key combination.

---

If you would like to prevent NERDCommenter from adding *all* its mappings, you can use this in your vimrc:

```
let g:NERDCreateDefaultMappings = 0
```

See [`:help 'NERDCreateDefaultMappings'`](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter/blob/c62e618a1ab5a50a4028e3296500ba29d9b033d8/doc/NERD_commenter.txt#L641).

Unfortunately it seems there's no granular way to prevent it from adding *one* mapping only (if you wanted to leave one or a few functions without key-bindings), it's all or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that plugins have "actions" that you can call with `:call`.

For example to map `Alt+;` to nerdcomment toggle:

```
nnoremap <M-;> :call NERDComment(0,"toggle")<CR>
vnoremap <M-;> :call NERDComment(0,"toggle")<CR>
```

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30831547/1663462

Comment: Welcome to this site Chris! Just a clarification about vocabulary: something that you can call with `call` is a "function", see [`:h user-functions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#user-functions). And of course they exists only with the plugin author decides to expose them to the user :)