# What does <Plug> do in vim?

Tags: neovim

I came across `<Plug>` in this command of easy-motion

```
nmap <Leader>w <Plug>(easymotion-overwin-w)
```

I tried to search for the definition of  but no luck. What does it mean?

Does it have anything related with sourcing `init.vim`(I am using nvim)? I am asking because I found this mapping won't work initially, and I have to source `$MYVIMRC` manaually to make it work.

Comment: Have you tried [`:h <Plug>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3cPlug%3e)? [How do I navigate to topics in Vim's documentation?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/1841)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that. I have just looked it up and it said: 
` The special key name "<Plug>" can be used for an internal mapping, which is      
  not to be matched with any key sequence.  This is useful in plugins           
  using-<Plug>. `
I guess it is used by the plugin itself internally, preventing users from modifying it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is used by plugin authors to make complex mappings available to the user. In a plugin code you define a mapping with `<plug>...` which is not a real key sequence but which can be used as a right hand side expression in a mapping by your users.

As an example take [this line of code](https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-subversive/blob/5695f97fc803767bf657a5e512daec19dd1fd786/plugin/subversive.vim#L8) from vim-subversive:

```
nnoremap <silent> <plug>(SubversiveSubstitute) :<c-u>call subversive#singleMotion#preSubstitute(v:register, 0, '')<cr>:set opfunc=subversive#singleMotion#substituteMotion<cr>g@
```

The right hand side calls the plugin functions and a bunch of other vim commands to change a text object without modifying the unnamed register. The author wanted to let the user decide which key should execute this action. Also they don't want to decide on a particular key sequence as it could have already been used by another plugin. In the doc they could have said to use:

```
nnoremap <silent> <your-favorite-key> :<c-u>call subversive#singleMotion#preSubstitute(v:register, 0, '')<cr>:set opfunc=subversive#singleMotion#substituteMotion<cr>g@
```

And that would have worked but the users would have to copy this long command in their vimrc, it's not convenient or easy to read.

So instead the users created the mapping with `<plug>(SubversiveSubstitute)` which means that [you can use this expression as the right hand side of a mapping now](https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-subversive/blob/5695f97fc803767bf657a5e512daec19dd1fd786/README.md#substitute-motion). In their config users can simply add:

```
nmap gc <plug>(SubversiveSubstitute)
```

To remap `gc` to the long expression.

Note that here the user had to create a recursive mapping, otherwise `<plug>(SubserviceSubstitute)` is interpreted as a built-in list of command which will fail.

The help [`:h using-<Plug>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#using-%3cPlug%3e) does a great job at describing how this feature works.

Comment: _"the users would have to copy this long command in their vimrc, it's not convenient or easy to read."_ it also doesn't cope well with possible evolutions of the plugin. The author may decide to change the `{rhs}` part (I did that a few times already). Plug-mapping act as public interface, meant to be stable as well.

Comment: @LucHermitte That's definitely a good point.

Comment: To be fair, just autoload (and possibly map-expr) can do all this even better.

Comment: @Matt Really? At first I thought about including something like "Maybe it would be easier to put this complicated RHS expression in a command and let user call the command in their mappings" but I'm not sure how `map-expr` and autoload do the same.

Comment: @Matt. Not necessarily as a map-expr could be something quite complex as well (i.e. more than a single function call, but several may be). In the end we are back to the stable API provided by plug-mappings. It also has to be a string, which complicates sequences. BTW I remember map-expr has a few limitations regarding cursor movements: they have to be returned.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I get the point now

Comment: @LucHermitte 1. Map-expr to some foo#bar(); 2. foo#bar() checks mode(); 3. If "visual" build and return visual-mode command string; 4. If "normal" set opfunc and return "g@". Opfunc is a closure to access foo#bar() params. If stable (non-parameterized) API required then export "partials" instead.

Answer (score 8):

`<plug>` mappings are meant as customization points. Not everyone will want to use the same shortcut/keybinding as the one chosen by the author of a plugin.

That's where `<plug>` mappings come in handy. The plugin author can provide a default keybinding (for a given feature of his/her plugin) and still permit end users of the plugin to use another keybinding (for personal taste or to avoid name collisions).

The line you've shown us is typical of what an end-user will put in his/her `.vimrc` to override the plugin default shortcut associated to `<Plug>(easymotion-overwin-w)` -- in a plugin this line would have been protected by at least a test on `hasmapto('<Plug>(easymotion-overwin-w)')`.

The old vim tip on wikia(/fandom now) may explain it in better terms: [Mapping keys in Vim - Tutorial (Part 3)](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_3)#Use_of_.3CPlug.3E)

Now regarding why it doesn't work in our case. Well, 3 things:

1. first as you are using `<leader>` you'll need to set the leader key before the mapping is defined
2. the mapping needs to be defined -- if it's in your `.vimrc` or equivalent (`init.vim`), it should be automatical. Check `:scriptname` in doubt.
3. the plugin, the plug-mapping refers to, needs to be loaded

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I found out that my mapping was overridden by the plugin's own mapping. Are plugins source before or after `init.vim` is completed?

Comment: Usually plugins are loaded after: [`:h startup`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#startup) -- we can also load them manually in the `.vimrc`/`init.vim` (bad practice), but they'll still be loaded after in step 4. as per Vim documentation)

Comment: Just checked out `:h vimrc` and I get the idea now. Is `autocmd VimEnter ` and remap the keybinding there the solution?

Comment: Now, it's strange that your plugin is overriding your mapping. Plugin authors, that provide `<plug>`-mappings, usually know how to provide default mapping (w/ `hasmapto()` + `<unique>`  or a test on `maparg()`). I remember statox has written a really nice and complete Q/A regarding mapping debugging.

Comment: Found this question but now sure if it is the proper way of remapping:
https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/756/how-can-i-redefine-plugin-key-mappings

Comment: If the plugin is well written, what you've put in your `init` file should be enough -- otherwise, I consider this is a bug. `VimEnter` may indeed be a workaround -- the feature will be bound to two shortcuts/keybinding sequences instead of one though (this is why I consider it to be a bug)

Comment: The plugin I am using is easy-motion. By using `:map`, I found out that my mapping was replaced by `easymotion-prefix`. By resourcing my `init.vim`, it would then be replaced by `easymotion-overwin-w`

Comment: Unfortunately my vimscript reading skills and vim experience is not capable of determining what is a bug and what not. But this is really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Last thing, you should have a look at https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/how-to-debug-a-mapping to see which plugin is actually overriding your mapping -- as easymotion code seems fine to me.